# Meteor react logout event

Tags: meteor, reactjs, logout, meteor-accounts

I'm using meteor and react with meteor packages:
  `accounts-ui accounts-password`

I want to execute a function client side and maybe server side, whenever the current user is logging out or leaving the page.

How can I do that ?

EDIT: I added code I'm using for the login. It's simply the react-meteor tutoral
Code on Login Systems. I need an event handler for log out events.

```
export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
  // Use Meteor Blaze to render login buttons
  this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));


}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // Clean up Blaze view
  Blaze.remove(this.view);
}

render() {
  // Just render a placeholder container that will be filled in
  return <span ref="container" />;
 }
}
```

Comment: [Meteor.logout](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_logout)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the action that is fired when your user clicks the Logout Button, you call:

```
Meteor.logout( function() {
    // your code here, runs when user is successfully logged out
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find this action ?

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to add a onClick event in your logout button, when it's clicked, you should call a method previously declared. Using `Meteor.call( ... )` - like you can see here - https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/security-with-methods

Comment: I added my code to the first post, it's using a template, where I can't add to the code, maybe you can help

Comment: You can configure this following this part of the guide - http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#useraccounts-customizing-templates